# Numerical Solution of coupled SDE using Runge kutta

Tags: stochastic-calculus, simulation, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to find the Runge-Kutta scheme for the simulation of Coupled Stochastic Differential Equations.

This [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_method_(SDE)) gives the basic scheme for non coupled equations, and just states that for coupled equations the scheme is longer.

Can anyone point me out to some literature where the scheme is given. 
Thank you for help.

(I have no background in mathematics and have little knowledge of stochastic differential equations. I would want the code for the simulation of a biological model)

Comment: Can you writ euler maruyama for that system ?

Comment: I do not know about the euler maruyama. Is it so that if I can write euler maruyama I can make the runga kutta scheme?

Comment: Euler method is basic method .The very first method

Comment: I understand that. But I have been told, it requires a very small time step and the solutions are difficult to converge

Comment: Can you post you dynamical system here  ?

Comment: Also look at the [Milstein method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milstein_method) that corrects the lowest-order error term of the Euler Maruyama method. In the linked original article the multi-dimensional method is also explained.

Comment: thank you guys, it has been solved. 
I used the leapfrog method as suggested by my supervisor.